# What is the past participle of the verb open?

Tags: verbs, past-participles

I'm French and I'd like to be precise on the conjugation of the verb "open".
On this picture, I'd write "opened" instead of "open". Could you tell me more about why they have written "open"?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because "open" is the simplest form of the word as adjective. "Opened" is more often used as a verb. So we say "Is the door open or is it closed?

Comment: So, is there any meaning differences between "the door had been opened" and "the door was open" (regardless to the tenses)? Is it also correct to write: "the door was opened"?

Comment: @Gael "The door had been opened" signifies that, at some fixed point in the past, someone observed that someone had opened the door previously. "The door was open", on the other hand, signifies not only that the door had been opened, but that it had not been closed. So the door might have been opened, but may not have remained so. Note that it's also possible to manufacture a door in the open position. In that case, one would say "the door was open", but it would be technically incorrect to say that "the door had been opened".

Comment: In that sense, this answer is spot-on: opened, even when used as an adjective, references the associated action on the item, whereas open has mainly to do with the item itself.

Comment: @Gael, consider in French _la porte était ouverte_ vs. _la porte a(vait) été ouverte_; the difference is more or less the same. _Open_ is a pure adjective that describes the **state** of something, while _opened_ is a participle that focuses on the **action** of opening the door.

Answer (score 1):

"Open" is correct because it's an adjective. 
*An open world* is a world with fewer closed doors (barriers), presumably.

But I wouldn't trust anything that guys says about his company's "mission."

Comment: I do not know who is this guy. I found that picture on a joke website:)

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know, it's Zuckerberg, the bazillionaire who started/runs Facebook.